# Rails Joins Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Model.joins(:model2)` creates

```
select models.* from models Inner Join ..............
```

I want to specify particular column name out here how can I do this. I would prefer a rails method over a query.

If not possible let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select particular column using select

Eg: Model.joins(:model2).select("column_name")

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
Model.select(:name).joins(:model2)
Model.select('model.name1, model.name2, model2.name').joins(:model2)
```